# Não consigo clicar no link - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá,
alguém pode me ajudar [postei o código também no codepen](https://codepen.io/brunopereiradonascimento/pen/LBowbq), não consigo clicar no link e abri o arquivo PDF, o que acontece é o slideUp da div.

**Desde já muito obrigado pela atenção!**

```js
(function($) { 
    $('.pasta').click(function() {
        $(this).children('.slide-lista').slideToggle('slow');
      return false;
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.pasta{ cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid tomato }
.slide-lista{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <ul>
                                  <li class="pasta"><strong>Indicador 1-1</strong>
                                    <div class="slide-lista"><ul>
                                  <li class="pasta"><strong>Projeto de Autoavaliação</strong>
                                    <div class="slide-lista"><ul><li class="arquivos"><a class="p-2" href="arquivos/Avaliação 6º ciclo 2018_2020.pdf" target="blank">Projeto Avaliação 6º ciclo 2018_2020.pdf</a></li></ul>    </div>
                                  </li>
                                </ul><ul>
                                  <li class="pasta"><strong>Relato Institucional</strong>
                                    <div class="slide-lista"><ul><li class="arquivos"><a class="p-2" href="arquivos/Relato Institucional.pdf" target="blank">Relato Institucional.pdf</a></li></ul>    </div>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>    </div>
                                  </li>
                                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o link faz parte do evento click da classe `.pasta`, adicione uma exceção à classe `.p-2` (que está dentro da classe `.pasta`) com `stopPropagation()`. Desta forma ao clicar no link com a classe `.p-2` não irá chamar o evento click da classe `.pasta`:

```js
(function($) { 
    $('.pasta').click(function() {
        $(this).children('.slide-lista').slideToggle('slow');
      return false;
    });    
})(jQuery);

$(".p-2").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.pasta{ cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid tomato }
.slide-lista{ display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pasta"><strong>Indicador 1-1</strong>
<div class="slide-lista"><ul>
<li class="pasta"><strong>Projeto de Autoavaliação</strong>
<div class="slide-lista"><ul><li class="arquivos"><a class="p-2" href="arquivos/Avaliação 6º ciclo 2018_2020.pdf" target="blank">Projeto Avaliação 6º ciclo 2018_2020.pdf</a></li></ul>    </div>
</li>
</ul><ul>
<li class="pasta"><strong>Relato Institucional</strong>
<div class="slide-lista"><ul><li class="arquivos"><a class="p-2" href="arquivos/Relato Institucional.pdf" target="blank">Relato Institucional.pdf</a></li></ul>    </div>
</li>
</ul>    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Valeu brother! 100%!!!!!!